# Does Google index/crawl display:none divs?

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, css, google-index

My website has a message on the index file and it will be shown on a special condition. When I search for my site via keywords, google search shows the message.

My code looks like as below

```
 <div id="splashPage" style="display:none">
          <div class="page-note">
            <p class="page-help">For
              instructions on how to resolve this issue contact admin . Thank you!.</p>
          </div>

        </div>
```

On some special condition, the message "For instructions on how to resolve this issue contact admin. Thank you!" will be displayed on the index page.

By default, the div will be display properly will have the value **none** via JavaScript and users will not see the div and the message. For special users who access our website via query parameters like `index.html?cc=splashMessage` will able to see the message by enabling the div display with value block.

In the google search engine, when I search about my website it always shows my website with the splash message. Google indexed my index file with the splash message, also via Google analytics I didn't see traffic via query parameters.

How to ignore this splash message on google search results from SEO?

Answer (score 1):

According to this author's opinion, Google crawls display:none which is what your trying to hide.  http://bayareaseosolutions.com/2015/11/30/does-google-crawl-css-displaynone-content/

Can you create the div with javascript or jquery so that your div doesn't exist, or at least doesn't contain any text without the querystring parameter, rather than hiding it?